# JAXB, REST to send XML object to remote URL

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, jaxb

There seem to be so many versions out there. Here is what I am doing. I have a RESTful webservice, and am trying to marshall a Java object into JAXB and send it over the wire to a webservice. Here is my client side code

```
 private static void performPost(JAXBObject obj) {
     String url ="http://www.example.com/test?xml=";


     HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
     urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
     urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
     urlConnection.setRequestProperty("accept-charset", charset);
     urlConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     urlConnection.setRequestProperty("accept", jsonContentType);

     JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBObject.class);
     Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
     jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
     jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, urlConnection.getOutputStream());  
     int rspCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
     ...
 }
```

The webservice code is

```
@POST   
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("test")
public String doIt(@QueryParam("xml") String str) {
    int ret = doSomething(str);
    return new Gson().toJson(ret);
}
```

The program is reaching doIt, but nothing is coming through in String str.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you actually setting the body of your request?

Comment: Doesn't the 'marshal' set the body? i.e. jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, urlConnection.getOutputStream());

Comment: @user2689782 - Yes the `marshal` operation sets the body, the issue you are encountering is where you are trying to retrieve the XML: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24250583/383861

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your question is sending the XML as the message, but is trying to receive it as a query parameter.  If you mean to send the XML as the message then the `str` parameter should not be annotated with `@QueryParam`.  A query param is the portion of the URL that appears after the ? (i.e.  for http://www.example.com/foo/bar?limit=25, `limit` is the query parameter).  You are trying to capture the body of the XML message which doesn't require an annotation.

Comment: Oh, I see, so I can't send a "http://www.example.com/test?xml=" so that I can pass multiple xml files? Just one output stream of an xml file, I suppose....

Comment: @user2689782 - You want to send multiple XML files in a single request?

Comment: Yes, I did...I guess I will have to find a way around it.